# How to use a part of URL to filter models? (using tastypie)

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie

Hello this is my first post. I have an api app using tastypie. It reads models from database. I would like to use a part of the api url to filter on certain objects. No arguments, just a part of url. For example, in an url : /api/cars/:registration/​ I would like to filter for any car with this registration.

I spent countless hours trying every option I have found on the web. It appears to me that the best option would be overriding get_object_list, but somehow I can't make it work.

models.py

```py
class Cars(models.Model):
    car_registration = models.Int()
    signal_time = models.DateTimeField()
    pos_x = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    pos_y = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
```

urls.py

```py
cars_resource = CarsResource()

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/<int:registration>/', include(cars_resource.urls)),
]
```

resources.py

```py
class CarsResource(ModelResource):

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        registration = self.kwargs['registration']
        return super(CarsResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(car_registration=registration)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Cars.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'cars'
```

In result I usually get 404 error. I have a feeling that I am doing something wrong, but can't really find that place.

Comment: why not just use the [basic filtering](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html#basic-filtering) provided by tastypie?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a url like `/api/cars/?registration=123`